# Redirecting from port 80 to different ports based on URL

Tags: routes, port, redirect

I have two applications, (Atlassian JIRA and Confluence,) listening on ports 8080 and 8090, accessible through example.com:8080/jira and example.com:8090/confluence.
I would like to set up a redirection on port 80 such that I can access the services through example.com/jira and example.com/confluence.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: It would be helpful to indicate which web server you are using (and add the appropriate tag).

Comment: Sorry for that Levi, I only had the two applications up and running and no other web server running alongside them. I was searching for the most simple way to redirect from scratch, and have now found a solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 ways of solving this.

**Redirect Method**

1. You seem pretty savvy setting up servers. You will need a web Server running on port 80. (Apache: Windows/*nix; IIS: Windows)
2. Set up a virtual site / folder if you just want example.com/jira and example.com/confluence. You could also do jira.example.com and confluence.example.com if you had your DNS records pointing to the host.
3. Use a 302 Redirect (temporary/found) to redirect a browser hitting this URL/Virtual Host to the new URL. This method changes the URL in the browser so the browser actually shows the 8080 and 8090 ports.

**Proxy Method**

The other way, if you wanted transparent URLs would be to set up reverse proxies on the 2 URLs. This way the proxy server on port 80 responds to the client as if the content is originating from port 80. The web server fetches the pages in the background and serves them up. You have the added benefit of caching content using a reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks Abhi.  
I looked into the 302 redirects but wasn't sure how to map them without /jira and /confluence actually pointing files rather than just being virtual directories.  
I took the idea however and found that I could use the Apache httpd server to redirect in another way. Through the httpd.conf I added the following lines:  
'Redirect temp /jira example.com:8080/jira' and  
'Redirect temp /confluence example.com:8090/confluence'  
This worked like a charm in testing and I will be implementing it shortly!

Comment: Nice. Yep. That should od the trick.
Also, as an FYI; You can use a 301 redirect, but that is considered a permanent redirect and you might have issues if you ever change URLs. 301s are usually cached indefinitely in a browser. Good luck.

Comment: How would you set reverse proxy so that all traffic on example.com goes to port 8069 except example.com/wp/* which is to go to port 80?

Comment: You could try URL Rewriting. That way you can force different URL based on regular expressions to go to different locations.