# How to redirect different URLs to different ports on the same domain?

Tags: redirect, apache2, port, odoo, reverse-proxy

I have odoo running on port 8069 and I want to run wordpress on port 80 on the same domain.  I would like to redirect example.com* to port 8069 except example.com/wordpress* which I want to go to port 80.

I know this is similar to [Redirecting from port 80 to different ports based on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997071/redirecting-from-port-80-to-different-ports-based-on-url).  I want to implement a reverse proxy solution as advised by abhi-devireddy.  I tried the following reverse proxy.  All requests are forwarded to port 8069 including `http://example.com/wordpress/`. Odoo reports error 404 page not found when browser points to `http://example.com/wordpress`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName odoo
        ErrorLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-access.log combined

        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / http://example.com:8069/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8069/

        ProxyPass http://example.com/wordpress/ http://example.com:80/wordpress
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/wordpress/ http://example.com:80/wordpress


        ProxyVia On
        LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProxyPass !` excludes the URL `http://example.com:80/wordpress` from the reverse proxy.  This allows everything except `http://example.com:80/wordpress` to be mapped to port 8069 while leaving `http://example.com:80/wordpress` to go through to port 80:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName odoo
        ErrorLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-access.log combined

        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass /wordpress !
        ProxyPass / http://example.com:8069/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8069/

        Alias /wordpress /var/lib/wordpress/

        # ProxyVia On
        LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```