# redirecting port using apache server

Tags: apache

I have two websites http://localhost:8000/abc and http://localhost:9000/def each deployed on its own apache server. Is there any way I can omit the port and use the apache server to divert to the respective ports by mapping from the url?

For example:
http://localhost/abc mapped to port 8000
http://localhost/def mapped to port 9000

Comment: ,aybe useful? [Redirecting from port 80 to different ports based on URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997071/redirecting-from-port-80-to-different-ports-based-on-url). Also? [Apache: forward one port to another with mod_proxy.](https://community.rackspace.com/products/f/18/t/1760)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed, the simplist way to do this would be a proxy. 
You could install ngenx and configure it with:

_ _ngenix_config_file__

```
location /abc {
    rewrite /abc/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /def {
    rewrite /def/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

That should do what you want. Of course now we have 3 websites.
If the other 2 are literally running off the same Apache instance, 
it might make more sense to rewrite your apache config to combine them. 
However regardless of what's going on with them, the above should work.

Comment: i tried this and the url is able to rewrite through the proxy server. But it is unable to retrieve the resources from the "real" server.